# How to make Ruby method end/stop another request ? (rails API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, error-handling, request

I have an API endpoint for a show request, something like this:

```
def show
  login
  data = get_data
  render json: data
end
```

I want to handle an error at login method, if login fail I want to end the `show` request from login method.

```
def login
  # do the login with username and password
  # if login is ok, continue the show request
  # else stop show request from this method
end
```

Is this possible?
How can I do that?

Comment: `before_filter -> { head(401) unless login }`

Comment: @potashin, `before_action` is prefered rather than `before_filter` (I think the later is deprecated now)

Comment: @arieljuod: my bad, old habits

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
class V1::LoginsController < ApplicationController

skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

end
```

Comment: While this answer might resolve the OP's question, it is suggested that you explain how it works and why it resolves the issue. This helps new developers understand what is going on and how to fix this and similar issues themselves. Thanks for contributing!